# How to use rigidbody.addforce for a bullet in a 2D game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, rigid-bodies

I'm a beginner in unity and I want to recreate a 2D turn based game like worms. I have a turret and a bullet. The problem that I have is that I cant use this code because Im using colliders and rigidbodies in 2D, I checked in the documentation and there's a rigidbody.addforce in 2D but I don't understand how to use it. This question may be silly but bear with me.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { 
        rigidbody.AddForce(5, 5, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c){
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Platform") {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this:

```
    rigidbody.AddForce (5,5,0,ForceMode.Impulse);
```

to 2D equivalent:

```
    rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(5, 5), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Also if you have 2D colliders attached to the gameObjects you need to use `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead of `OnCollisionEnter`

PS. If you want just the force to affect to the speed remove this line:

```
    transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
```